# Como criar um DASHBOARD igual a esse?!

Tags: html5, css3

Vou ter que criar tudo em DIV? Alguém pode fazer um exemplo dessa " LINHA A " para eu poder seguir? O resto eu consegui criar, só essas " LINHA A, B, C ... " que estou tendo dificuldade de " empilhar " do mesmo jeito que está na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque aqui o código do que você já fez

Comment: Vish. Estou no trabalho, deixei o arquivo em casa. Esqueci de enviar ele pro meu e-mail. Mas eu fiz aquele cabeçalho ali, " OEE DASHBOARD e os ícones da empresa " e a parte de baixo ali " Planejado(turno) etc " e o footer lá embaixo " WHS Dashboard ".

Comment: Estou com dificuldade apenas de fazer essas " LINHA A, B, C, D ... " deixar "empilhado" como está na imagem, porcentagem, as bolinhas ali, rate, head, meta, real...

Comment: Está utilizando **bootstrap** ou fazendo tudo do zero?

Comment: Fazendo tudo do zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem n formas de montar esse layout, segue uma *alternativa* que vai te dar um "norte" de como fazer aquelas `divs` das linhas, deixei um exemplo da estrutura básica do layout, é tudo questão de [exibição](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) e [posicionamento](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) , trabalha dentro destas estruturas que tu vai chegar em algo bem parecido, espero que ajude.

```css
.painel-principal {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.bloco-painel {
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.cabecalho-bloco {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="painel-principal">
  <div class="bloco-painel">
    <div class="cabecalho-bloco">
      LINHA A
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bloco-painel">
    <div class="cabecalho-bloco">
      LINHA B
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bloco-painel">
    <div class="cabecalho-bloco">
      LINHA C
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bloco-painel">
    <div class="cabecalho-bloco">
      LINHA D
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Já me deu uma luz. Agradeço de coração Mathias :D